# Facebook Method: Feed - JavaScript - Body OnLoad

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First: I'm not English and my English is not very good, then sorry.
I have some problem with my FB App.

This is the code:

```
//My Script
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<p><a onload="postToFeed(); return false;"> </a></p>

<p id="msg"></p>

<script>
  FB.init({appId: "********", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: "feed",
      link: "http://apps.facebook.com/bachflower/",
      picture: "http://glacial-hollows-5787.herokuapp.com/images/37p.png",
      name: "Wild Rose - Rosa Canina",
      caption: " ",
      description: "Dona: Decisione, motivazione, accettazione con gioia del quotidiano. Chi ne ha bisogno tende a pensare: Non vale la pena… meglio rinunciare. Non serve a nulla… - App by medicinanaturale.pro"
    };

    function callback(response) {

    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>

//This is my body OnLoad
<body text="#000000" onLoad="postToFeed();" >
```

The problem is:
Some people can see and share correctly on their wall the postToFeed notice.
And some people can't see anything about postToFeed.
Why?

Anyone can help me?

Than you,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

The postToFeed() function might be called before FB is loaded and initialized.
Use asynchronous loading, like this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
           appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
           channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File for x-domain communication
           status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
           cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
           xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        postToFeed();

    };

  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
    (function(d, debug){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
       ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
```

See here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/